# Having to check both discriminators. Generic Discriminated Union Type

Tags: typescript, generics, discriminated-union, union-types, narrowing

I have these interfaces

```js
interface BaseState {
  isError: boolean;
  errorMessage: string;
}

interface IPState extends BaseState {
  ip: string;
  type: 'ip';
}

interface LocationState extends BaseState {
  city: string;
  countryCode: string;
  type: 'location';
}

interface TimezoneState extends BaseState {
  timezone: string;
  type: 'timezone';
}

type DialogState = IPState | LocationState | TimezoneState;

enum DialogActionType {
  ERROR = 'ERROR',
  DATA = 'DATA',
}

interface DialogAction<T extends DialogState> {
  type: DialogActionType;
  payload: T;
}
```

and this function (simplified)

```
export default function dialogReducer<T extends DialogState>(
  state: T,
  action: DialogAction<T>,
) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case DialogActionType.DATA:
      if (state.type === 'ip') {
        return {
          ...state,
          ip: action.payload.ip,
        };
}
```

the type of `state` after checking the discriminator is `IPState`. The type of `action.payload` isnt though

if check both discriminators:

```js
if (state.type === 'ip' && action.payload.type === 'ip') {
  return {
    ...state,
    ip: action.payload.ip,
  };
}
```

the type of `action.payload` is correct too

Is there a way so I dont have to check both?